# Why isn't PDFBox printing a document using landscape orientation?

Tags: java, printing, pdfbox, jpedal

I have a problem printing a landscape document `(doc.width > doc.height)`.  I have no problem with portrait.  I'm using the PDFBox 1.8.2 library.  It prints the document in portrait even if I set landscape mode manually like in [this blog](http://pk345.blogspot.com/2012/11/pdfbox-landscape-printing-problem-and.html). There are several [closed JIRA bugs](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-985) about this problem in the PDFBox project.  How do I print landscape?

Note: I've added extra PDF library tags to flag users of those libraries to see if this problem exists in those libraries.

Code from the blog post:

```
Version : PdfBox-1.7.1 

PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(psStream,true);

if (printService != null) {             

    PrinterJob pj =  PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.defaultPage();
    pj.setCopies(Integer.parseInt(finalnumberOfCopies));
    pj.setPrintService(printService);
    pj.setPageable(new MyPDPageable(doc,pj));

    // don't use doc.silentPrint(pj) but pj.print() ...
    pj.print();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code surrounding your print attempts and the versions of the PDFBox and JRE you are using.

Comment: Try the unreleased 2.0 version, we recently solved several problems with landscape printing.

Answer (score 0):

This example at [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.2.0/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreateLandscapePDF.java) worked for me. To summarize, it first rotates a portrait page 90 degrees to get the landscape orientation, and then uses the concatenate2CTM method to similarly rotate your contentStream.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).